# Removing special characters from column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used `to_flat_index()` to flatten columns and ended up with column names like `('Method', 'sum')`. I am trying to remove the special characters from these. But when I try to remove them, it changes all the column names to `nan`

function attempted:
`df_pred.columns = df_pred.columns.str.replace("[(,),']", '')`

Expected outcome: `MethodSum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your columns are multi-indexed because your use `to_flat_index`.

```py
>>> df
        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux
        one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
0  0.713825  0.015553  0.036683  0.388443  0.729509  0.699883  0.125998  0.407517
1  0.820843  0.259039  0.217209  0.021479  0.845530  0.112166  0.219814  0.527205
2  0.734660  0.931206  0.651559  0.337565  0.422514  0.873403  0.979258  0.269594
3  0.314323  0.857317  0.222574  0.811631  0.313495  0.315072  0.354784  0.394564
4  0.672068  0.658103  0.402914  0.430545  0.879331  0.015605  0.086048  0.918678
```

Try:

```py
>>> df.columns.to_flat_index().map(''.join)
Index(['barone', 'bartwo', 'bazone', 'baztwo',
       'fooone', 'footwo', 'quxone', 'quxtwo'],
      dtype='object')
```